# Accessing Application.Resources from a DLL

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5

I defined a resource in App.xaml in Application.Resources in a WPF application (exe).

I have a dll which will be referenced by the exe. In this dll, I have a Window that needs to use the resource defined in Application.Resources.

How can I do this?